# Session lost when refreshed

Tags: php, session

I have recently moved my site on to the main domain of my website.

I am finding that when I log into my site, the account page shows but the sessions are lost when I refresh or when an ajax call is made, logging me out. I have an iframe on my account page and i have recently just installed SSL.

Any ideas why my session's are being lost? Or are there any ways I could find the type of error?

My php info is :

```
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   On  On
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
```

The errors I get when I put on error reporting is :

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  adminsess in <b>/home/onclick1/public_html/admin.php</b> on line <b>35</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  secure in <b>/home/onclick1/public_html/admin.php</b> on line <b>36</b><br />
<br />
```

The code that gives the error is simple:

```
<?php 
session_start();
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
require "connectTo/db.php";

if(!isset($_SESSION['adminsess']) || !isset($_SESSION['secure']) ){
        //exit(); *comment out to give error*
    }
```

I have gone through my code and found out that the error seems to only occur (unable to store session data) when i add a header() redirect on the index page. The code i have on the site to redirect users who have logged in is below:

If the redirect header is used.. it just loops and doesnt load the page

```
<?php 
session_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);

//print_r($_SERVER);

//exit;
$TheIp=ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$ip= trim($TheIp);


include('mobile.php'); 
require "db.php";

$_SESSION['secureip'] = $ip;

if(isset($_SESSION['adminsess']))
    {
    $ipVistor = $ip;
    $ipVistorSalt= $ipVistor."28257esfgs";
    $ip=md5($ipVistorSalt);

    $userAgent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $userAgentSalt=$userAgent."jk2hgkj22352523s";
    $agent=md5($userAgentSalt);

    if(isset($_SESSION['secure']) && $_SESSION['secure']==$ip)
    {

    if (isset($_SESSION['secure2']) && $_SESSION['secure2'] == $agent) 
    {    
        //header("Location: https://www.site.com/admin?Welcome");
        exit();
    } 
    }
    }

?>
```

Any help / info would be great. Thanks in advance !

---

Even if i put this at the very top of the page it trys to load index2.php but just keeps looping... is this a server issue ?? (index2 is just a copy of index).

```
<?php 
header("Location: https://www.site.com/index2.php");
exit;
```

Comment: I think there is another issue here, probably with the way you setup the session or how you are using it so the PHP code is really needed. Specially as the iFrame may be getting inbetween and the errors you pasted make no sense without the code.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `iframe`?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The iframe is used to display content.. such as a 'friends' page. I had the website in a folder and it all worked.. and when i moved out the folder.. the sessions dont work... could this be a server problem ??

Comment: Oh also the sessions is used just to see if the user has logged in or not. Thanks again

Comment: Hi, @Toote what do u mean about setup, can you please let us know what info shall i also paste in ?

Comment: can you describe exactly what you mean by "moved out the folder"?

Comment: i use to have the site under the folder: www.site.com/testing/ i then took all the content out of the testing folder and put it into the root (/www) folder. I have been going through every single line of code and have found out that... if I use header("Location: https://www.site.com/admin"); to redirect from my index page (only).. then the sessions dont get stored?? .. does anyone know how this can happen or has seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the session name:

```
session_name("foo");
```

Or in the runtime config:

```
session.name foo
```

make sure you're calling `session_start()` and the ajax call isn't on another domain.